# Node with Mysql2 timezone issue

Tags: node.js, nodes, mysql2, node-mysql2

**When I am trying to set the timezone with mysql2 getting the bellow message.**
**With MySQL working fine.**

**But I have to use mysql2 only**

```
var mysql2 = require('mysql2');

var con = mysql2.createPool({  
connectionLimit : 10, 
host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST, 
user: process.env.DATABASE_USER,  
password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,  
database : process.env.DATABASE_NAME,  
timezone : 'IST'      
})
```

**Problem**

> Ignoring invalid timezone passed to Connection: IST. This is currently
> a warning, but in future versions of MySQL2, an error will be thrown
> if you give an invalid configuration option to a Connection

Comment: does timezone accepts IST?

Answer (score 2):

Here try this as `timezone`.  For **IST**

```
timezone: 'Asia/Calcutta'

or

timezone: '+05:30'
```

Comment: not working getting this error
Ignoring invalid configuration option passed to Connection: dialectOptions. This is currently a warning, but in future versions of MySQL2, an error will be thrown if you pass an invalid configuration option to a Connection
Ignoring invalid timezone passed to Connection: Asia/Calcutta. This is currently a warning, but in future versions of MySQL2, an error will be thrown if you pass an invalid configuration option to a Connection

Comment: Updated my answer can you check now ?

Comment: again not working
timezone : 'IST' is working with MySQL but not working in mysql2

Comment: It's working just fine in 2022.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the description about `timezone` in [mysqljs/mysql](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#connection-options):

> timezone: The timezone configured on the MySQL server. This is used to type cast server date/time values to JavaScript Date object and vice versa. This can be 'local', 'Z', or an offset in the form +HH:MM or -HH:MM. (Default: 'local')

You need to use `+05:30` instead of `Asia/Calcutta`.